# How to change the version of bundler being used in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, rubygems, bundler

When I run the following command, it gives me the available installed versions of bundler:

command :

```
gem list | grep "bundle"
```

output:

```
bundler (1.11.2, 1.10.6, 1.10.4, 1.3.6, 1.3.0, 1.3.0.pre)
```

The current version of bundler I obtained was 1.11.2 using the following command:

```
bundler --version
```

I want to use version 1.3.6
How do I swap the current version of bundler with the available ones?

Comment: Its September 2019. Still, there is no way to forcefully use a specific version of bundler from all of the installed ones?

Answer (score 15):

Normally during development Bundler is used from it's executable on your system, so I don't believe you can specify a specific version in your Gemfile, for example.  (You might try it, though).  However, you can install the version you like and force the shell/rubygems to use that version:

```
$ gem install bundler -v 1.3.6
...
1 gem installed

$ bundle _1.3.6_ -v
Bundler version 1.3.6
```

To get my machine to use 1.3.6 by default I had to uninstall 1.11.2.

Update:  I tried specifying `gem 'bundler', '~> 1.3'` in one of my projects and it worked, although the CLI for bundler still used the system default version.

Comment: After doing so, When I run the bundler --version command, it still shows 1.11.2, how so?

Comment: You have to add `_1.3.6_` every time unless you remove your other versions

Comment: I just updated my answer.  Another good question would be, how to force rubygems to use a specific version of an installed gem's executable?  As for that, I do not know.  I think I'll make a question for that though, because now I'm curious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703958/how-to-force-rubygems-or-shell-to-use-a-certain-version-of-a-gems-executable

Comment: You can use `bundle exec` to run the command you want with the bundler version specified in your project. E.g.: `bundle exec rails s` will run the `rails s` with the bundler specified in the Gemfile of your current project.

Answer (score 9):

### Sept 2019

**If you want to upgrade bundler 1 to 2**, then you should do the following:

1- The first step in upgrading to Bundler 2 is installing the Bundler 2 gem by running:

`gem install bundler`

2- When Bundler 2 installed, Bundler will automatically switch between version 1 and version 2 based on your application’s Gemfile.lock based on the `BUNDLED WITH ((version))` in your Gemfile.lock

***Note:***

Before the next step, you should commit your Gemfile & Gemfile.lock, so that you can revert to bundler version 1 if needed

3- To upgrade from bundler 1 to 2, run:

`bundle update --bundler`

The answer is based on the [official bundler update guide](https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html)

Comment: running `bundle update --bundler` updated my lock file

Answer (score -6):

To change your bundler default version, use `bundle config default <the desired version>`.