# How to force rubygems or shell to use a certain version of a gem's executable?

Tags: bash, rubygems, bundler

For example, I can install v1.3.6 of bundler on my machine, but the shell will still use v1.11.2:

```bsh
$ gem install bundler -v 1.3.6
...
1 gem installed

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.11.2
```

To actually *use* v1.3.6, I have to either explicitely say so every time or uninstall v1.11.2:

```bsh
$ bundle _1.3.6_ -v
Bundler version 1.3.6

$ gem uninstall bundler -v 1.11.2
...

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.3.6
```

How I can I keep earlier versions of Bundler installed (like 1.11.2) but change the default to another version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure your limitations, but why don't you alias the bundler?

in .bash_rc for one user, or in /etc/bashrc for all users

`alias bundle='bundle _1.3.6_'`

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this a couple days ago.  I think this is the best solution, at the moment.  Thanks!