# Ruby: I cannot create gemfile.lock with default bundler version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I want to create my `gemfile.lock` file with bundler version 2.3.25

But when I try to `bundle install` it always is bundled with `2.4.5`

So I uninstall bundler version `2.4.5` and it STILL bundles with that version, and then throws errors when I `rails s` because version `2.4.5` isn't there.

When I run `gem list bundler` right now I get: `bundler (2.4.5, default: 2.3.25)`

I've gone as far as to delete the file from

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\me\.rbenv\versions\2.7.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.7.0\gems\bundler-2.4.5`

then, I delete the `gemfile.lock` file and `bundle install` and low and behold its bundled with `2.4.5`..

I've tried `gem uninstall bundler` and no luck..

I've tried all of the following methods and no luck
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761120/rails-how-to-change-bundler-default-version)
or
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703644/how-to-change-the-version-of-bundler-being-used-in-rails)

How can I either force Ruby to use the default version of Bundler, or REALLY get rid of the version I don't want?

Comment: You can run `bundle _<version>_ <command>` to use a specific version e.g. `bundle _2.3.25_ install` that being said is there a specific reason you want to use an older bundler version?

Comment: Thanks.. yes Heroku is throwing errors and I think that's why

Answer (score 0):

Bundler will add its version number to `Gemfile.lock` after you've run `bundle install`:

```yaml
BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.5
```

Therefore you can run `bundle install` with version 2.4.5 to generate `Gemfile.lock` and then edit it with a text editor to replace the version with the version you require. Then, when you run `bundle install` again bundler will notice that and will use the older version that you specify.

`Gemfile.lock` is a pretty straightforward and standard format and [there are no material changes to it](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/bundler/CHANGELOG.md) between those versions.

Otherwise, you can do like @engineersmnky said (and is explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885763/3784008)) and use:

```bash
bundle _2.3.25_ install
```

Comment: Yea, something else must be wrong, because I've tried both those methods. And my lock file is STILL bundled with 2.4.5 weird